# Dojo, xhrPost does not work with programmatically created form in a dialog

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, dojo, http-post

I'm creating "programmatically" a form in a dialog, this is shown correctly when the dom is ready.
Clicking the "Login" button, a POST request is correctly triggered ( I'm checking on chrome debugger ) however, it seems that the POST request does not contain any form data. No usernameF and passwordF parameters in the response.
The problem does not exists if I try to use xhrPost with a previously (i.e. statically ) instantiated form ( HTML, like all the examples found on the net).
What's the reason ?

Here's the code:

```
require([
    "dijit/Dialog",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dijit/form/TextBox",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/domReady!",
], function(Dialog, Form, TextBox, Button)
{
    var form = new Form({id: "loginformF"});

    var usernameF = new TextBox({
        id: "usernameF",
        placeHolder: "Username"
    });
    usernameF.placeAt(form.containerNode);

    var passwordF = new TextBox({
        id: "passwordF",
        placeHolder: "Password",
        type: 'password'
    });
    passwordF.placeAt(form.containerNode);

    new Button({
        id: "login",
        label: "Login",
        onClick: function(event) {

            //chiamata ajax
            dojo.xhrPost({
                url: "login.php",
                form: form.containerNode,
                load: function(data) {
                    console.log("Message posted.");
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log("Message posted.");
                }
            });
            console.log("Message being sent...");
        }
    }).placeAt(form.containerNode);

    //crea il dialog
    var dia = new Dialog({
        content: form,
        title: "Dialog with form"
    });
    //form.startup();
    dia.show();
});
```

Here's the dump of the request/response taken from the Chrome debugger, as you can see there's no "Form Data" section:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/cv.dojo/login.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:it,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/cv.dojo/?
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.67 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:10
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 02 Dec 2013 18:31:38 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=96
Server:Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.19
```

I would expect to find a section like this in the response:

```
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
usernameF:blablablablabla
passwordF:blablablablabla
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Damn! :)
Got it!

I simply forgot the "name" parameter in the input fields.

Here is the corrected code, look at

**name: "usernameF",**

and

**name: "passwordF",**

```
require([
    "dijit/Dialog",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dijit/form/TextBox",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/domReady!",
], function(Dialog, Form, TextBox, Button)
{
    var form = new Form({id: "loginformF"});

    var usernameF = new TextBox({
        id: "usernameF",
        name:"usernameF",
        placeHolder: "Username"
    });
    usernameF.placeAt(form.containerNode);

    var passwordF = new TextBox({
        id: "passwordF",
        name:"passwordF",
        placeHolder: "Password",
        type: 'password'
    });
    passwordF.placeAt(form.containerNode);

    new Button({
        id: "login",
        label: "Login",
        onClick: function(event) {

            //chiamata ajax
            dojo.xhrPost({
                url: "login.php",
                form: form.containerNode,
                load: function(data) {
                    console.log("Message posted.");
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log("Message posted.");
                }
            });
            console.log("Message being sent...");
        }
    }).placeAt(form.containerNode);

    //crea il dialog
    var dia = new Dialog({
        content: form,
        title: "Dialog with form"
    });
    //form.startup();
    dia.show();
});
```

Thanks anyway.